# CKEditor enable special characters (its stripping them)

Tags: ckeditor, grocery-crud

Im using CKEditor as a part of Grocery Crud (this is a php codeignihter crud setup), which uses CKEditor (3.6.5) to edit text fields.

So the problem im having is, some special characters (like `&#256;`) gets somewhat stripped from CKEditor (this happens in the latest version too). Can someone help me make sure these special characters gets treated correctly (specially if there is any flags that i can set maybe)?

To test, just open up a CKEditor anywhere (use the Full demo on the CKEditor website), click the "source" button (to see html mode), then paste the following in the editor: `&#256;`. Then click the source button again (to see the wysiwyg mode) and you will see a Letter `A` with a line above it. Then click the source again (to see html mode)  and you will see that the characters you entered `&#256;` have been replaced by the Letter A with the line above it.

Any thoughts about keeping CKEditor from stripping out the character codes?

The above only happens for some special characters (ones that uses decimal or hex codes) and not others which is a bit strange. And some character codes (that uses hex/decimal) get changed to some other codes (that has non hex/decimal alternatives, which is strange but atleast you end up with the same result).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, let me answer my own question.

You need to add the following to the config:

`config.entities_processNumerical = true;`

In the case of grocery crud, this is done on the following file: `/assets/grocery_crud/texteditor/ckeditor/config.js`

More doccumentation can be found here: http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.config.html#.entities_processNumerical

To be fair though, im surprised this is not enabled by default. Not quite sure why.